# How do small software patches correct big software?

Tags: patch, software-distribution

One thing I've always wondered about is how software patches work. A lot of software seems to just release new versions on their binaries that need to be installed over older versions, but some software (operating systems like Windows in particular) seem to be able to release very small patches that correct bugs or add functionality to existing software.

Most of the time the patches I see can't possibly replace entire applications, or even small files that are used within applications. To me it seems like the actual binary is being modified.

How are these kinds of patches actually implemented? Could anyone point me to any resources that explain how this works, or is it just as simple as replacing small components such as linked libraries in an application?

I'll probably never need to do a deployment in this manner, but I am curious to find out how it works. If I'm correct in my understanding that patches can really modify only portions of binary files, is this possible to do in .NET? If it is I'd like to learn it since that's the framework I'm most familiar with and I'd like to understand how it works.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is usually implemented using binary diff algorithms -- diff the most recently released version against the new code. If the user's running the most recent version, you only need to apply the diff. Works particularly well against software, because compiled code is usually pretty similar between versions. Of course, if the user's not running the most recent version you'll have to download the whole thing anyway.

---

There are a couple implementations of generic binary diff algorithms: [bsdiff](http://www.daemonology.net/bsdiff/) and [xdelta](http://code.google.com/p/xdelta/) are good open-source implementations. I can't find any implementations for .NET, but since the algorithms in question are pretty platform-agnostic it shouldn't be too difficult to port them if you feel like a project.

Comment: I'd replace "can be" by is or at least usually is.

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about patching windows applications then what you want to look at are .MSP files.  These are similar to an .MSI but just patch and application.

Take a look at [Patching and Upgrading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370579(VS.85).aspx) in the MSDN documents.

What an .MSP files does is load updated files to an application install.  This typically is updated dll's and resource files, but could include any file.

In addition to patching the installed application, the repair files located in C:\WINDOWS\Installer are updated as well.  Then if the user selects "Repair" from Add / Remove programs the updated patch files are used as well.

I'm thinking that the binary diff method discussed by John Millikin must be used in other operating systems.  Although you could make it work in windows it would be somewhat alien.